# How to re-run a view based off information on the current page

Tags: python, json, ajax, django

I'm using the django web framework to create a calendar webpage. I have a couple of buttons on the page a 'Next' and 'Previous' button that I want to change the values of some things on a view.

The change in values is dependant on what is currently on the page, so I have used ajax to get some information from the page and send it to the view. Here's the view:

```
def holiday(request):
    if request.is_ajax():     
        # find out if next or previous has been clicked
        request_type = request.GET['type']            
        if request_type == "next":  
            response_data = {}  

            # calculate new month and year based off current month and year from view 

            year = a_new_year
            month = a_new_month

        if request_type == "previous":

            #same again

    else:
        # page loaded for first time use current date
        date_today = datetime.now()
        year = date_today.year
        month = date_today.month

    my_holidays = Holiday.objects.order_by('start_date').filter(
        Q(start_date__year=year, start_date__month=month) | Q(end_date__year=year, end_date__month=month)
    )
    cal = HolidayCalendar(my_holidays, request.user).formatmonth(year, month)

    context = {
        "calendar": mark_safe(cal),
    }

    return render(request, "tande/calendar.html", context)
```

And then I have this ajax

```
$('#next').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'tande:holiday' %}",
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
            current: $('th.month').html(), 
            type: "next"
        },
        success : function (json) {
            console.log("hello");          
        }
    });
});
```

Basically, this doesn't work, because the response here is just the html for the page.

How do I run the view with
1) Information from the template - it's the content of a table header
2) Information on what button I pressed - I need the id of the button

and get it to render?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You *are* re-rendering the page; but your Ajax success method is not doing anything with the returned response, so it goes nowhere.

Comment: Yes - basically I don't know what to do now. I have managed to send data to the view - the stuff I need. And run the view. I suppose the question is what do I do now to get the page to refresh? @DanielRoseman

Comment: Well if you want the page to refresh completely I don't know why you are using Ajax at all; just make the months normal links. Otherwise your success function needs to insert the result into the existing page HTML using jQuery.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean, but I need to send information from the current page to the view. I need the contents of what is in a table header to find the current month so I can recalculate this. That's why I used ajax. If I use link won't I need a separate view for every month of the year? @DanielRoseman

Comment: I don't see why; your links could contain exactly the same information, as GET parameters.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I honestly don't know how I make things so complicated....

Comment: You are just learning the framework. It's part of the learning process. :) Once you get used to it, you'll find it more comfortable and easy to find solutions to your problems.

Answer (score -1):

You can't dynamically change things in the HTML with Django only. You'll need to use JavaScript for that. You can use [django-serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) to manage the data and then do a post-processing of your front-end.

1. Rebuild the page using a frond-end language (Javascript);

OR

2. Reload the page (F5).

Comment: Can I get the page to reload with javascript? like imitate an F5 press without the user having to do this?

Comment: Yeah, you can. It won't be really user friendly, but it will do the job. Later on you can implement something like ReactJS and other fancy libraries. :o) Or you can do like Daniel commented above.